# BitBucket: How to push a local repository that doesn't exist in the remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository on my local machine that I want to push to the remote. The repo doesn't exist on the remote yet. I tried to do:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

and I got:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts. conq: repository does not
>   exist. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have no problem to clone or to push to repositories that exist on the remote.

When I typed inside the directory I want to push, I got:

> $ git remote -v origin
>
> ssh://git@bitbucket.org/***/Checkers.git
>
> (fetch) origin    ssh://git@bitbucket.org/***/Checkers.git (push)

Comment: I usually go onto the Bitbucket UI and create the repository there. Then you can git push your local repo to it.

Comment: That also works for me. I was wondering if there is a quicker way.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible. But you can create new remote repository in few minutes, than commit and push your local data

Comment: You have to create the repository in the Bitbucket UI, as Sunil said, or via [the Bitbucket API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html), before you can push to it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the Bitbucket API via cURL, another (IMHO simpler) way to do this is to use [`bitbucket-cli`](https://bitbucket.org/zhemao/bitbucket-cli).

1. Install it using [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) 
    `pip install bitbucket-cli`
2. Then creating a repository is as simple as: 
    `bb create --private --protocol ssh --scm git YOUR_REPO_NAME`

Use `--public` for public access. If you wish to use a Username,  `--username YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE` is what you need.